# Adverb and adjective in sentences

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> As he didn’t like meal he want to make a few dollars short payment.
>
> As he didn’t like meal he want to make payment a few dollars shor .

Is there any difference between two sentence. I thought when I changed the place of “payment” the meaning doesn’t change but payment is used as an adjective in the first sentence and it is used as an adverb in the second sentence please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

First, "meal" is not an idiomatic verb. I suspect that what you mean

> As he didn't eat a meal, he [wants/wanted] to make his payment a few dollars short.

"Payment" is a noun, the direct object of "to make," rather than an adjective or adverb.

And

> As he didn't eat a meal, he [wants/wanted] to make a few dollars short payment

is not idiomatic at all.

"A few dollars short

is a phrase used as an adjective describing the payment, namely that is somewhat less than the amount ostensibly due. Adjectival phrases typically follow the noun being modified. You can think of the phrase in the first, correct sentence as being an ellipsis of the following modifying clause

> As he didn't eat a meal, he [wants/wanted] to make a payment that [will be/is/was] a few dollars short.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write”like”.

Comment: Ahh, but it still needs an article or possessive pronoun. "He did not like the meal" or "He did not like his meal."

Comment: I don't think he was using meal as a verb. He was saying "As he didn't like the meal, he didn't want to pay the full amount of the bill."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty You are correct as to what the OP intended, but not about the OP's **original** question. After I answered the **original** question, he edited his question to add a verb. It was an admittedly inadvertent typo, but it completely altered the question that I was responding to. If you look at the history of edits, you can see it.

Comment: Hey, Jeff, I'm new here. How do you get to the history of edits? Thanks.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Underneath the main body of the question and about level with the name of the person asking the question, you will see something entitled "edited. Click on it. It will take you to a copy of the question that shows what was added, deleted, or altered. It can be helpful. Frequently, answers can look a bit weird if the question is later edited.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, that sounds useful.